# Bug in google play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Google Play store reports [my apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koolbusiness) sizes as "null" but AFAIK my app is working. It says "null" where app size should be listed. Is this a bug?
[image]

At my other app, it says "size undefined".

[image]

Comment: Where is it showing null in play store or inside your phone after installation ?

Comment: @HarshGundecha In play store. I added screenshot. This is the case for two of my apps. I didn't check the third.

Comment: The app link you have posted takes me to the app named "Trending Ads(unreleased)" with last update date 29-mar-2018, please verify the link

Comment: @HarshGundecha Yes. It is my app. Size `null` is reported at two of my apps, here too https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.android.jamie

Comment: To me its showing 6.64 mb

Comment: @HarshGundecha maybe it is a feature that it shows different versions? I will look from another device.

Comment: My play store version is 8.9.24 and using moto g5+ on android 7.0 stock , hope that would help

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz facing the same issue. any workaround?

Comment: @Radhey I'm checking different apps from different devices. Will update with my findings.

Comment: I have capitalize one thing , not our apps but too many apps having the same issue over play store(which are published in this last 2 days ). I have just uploaded new build yesterday.might be you too @NiklasRosencrantz

Comment: Maybe we need to be more specific about the client. With Google Play Store native Android app, I see the app size. With webbrowsers, I see null there. I've tried Firefox Focus (Blink) and Firefox (Gecko), both of them behave this way. It is obviously a bug.

Comment: Its a bug from PlayStore itself, many of the app shows null size.

Comment: You should probably report this to Google. We aren't really going to be able to help aside from saying "yes, it looks like a bug".